# Bayesian hyperparameter optimization for XGBoost regression: cannot tune n_estimators?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, bayesian

My codes work for all other hyperparameters expect for n_estimators. However, when I added n_estimators, I got the error message like:

> WARNING: C:/buildkite-agent/builds/buildkite-windows-cpu-autoscaling-group-i-0fc7796c793e6356f-1/xgboost/xgboost-ci-windows/src/learner.cc:767:
> Parameters: { "n_estimators" } are not used.>

I can't figure out what is wrong.
Here are my codes:

```
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
def xgb_cv(max_depth, learning_rate, subsample, colsample_bytree, lambd, alpha, min_child_weight, gamma, scale_pos_weight, n_estimators):
    params = {
        'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
        'max_depth': int(max_depth),
        'learning_rate': learning_rate,
        'subsample': subsample,
        'colsample_bytree': colsample_bytree,
        'lambda': lambd,
        'alpha': alpha,
        'min_child_weight': min_child_weight,
        'gamma': gamma,
        'scale_pos_weight': scale_pos_weight,
        'n_estimators': int(n_estimators)
    }

    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = y_train)
    cv_result = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=100, early_stopping_rounds=10, nfold=10, metrics='error')
    return -cv_result['test-error-mean'].iloc[-1]


pbounds = {
    'max_depth': (3, 9),
    'learning_rate': (0.01, 0.5),
    'subsample': (0.1, 1),
    'colsample_bytree': (0.1, 1),
    'lambd': (1, 1),
    'alpha': (0, 0),
    'min_child_weight': (2, 10),
    'gamma': (0.1, 0.5),
    'scale_pos_weight': (1, 1),
    'n_estimators': (50, 500)
}

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(f=xgb_cv, pbounds=pbounds, random_state=100)
optimizer.maximize(init_points=5, n_iter=10)
```

I also tested without cross validation, the codes work:

```
# no cross-validation
def xgb_no_cv(max_depth, learning_rate, subsample, colsample_bytree, lambd, alpha, min_child_weight, gamma, scale_pos_weight, n_estimators):
    params = {
        'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
        'max_depth': int(max_depth),
        'learning_rate': learning_rate,
        'subsample': subsample,
        'colsample_bytree': colsample_bytree,
        'lambda': lambd,
        'alpha': alpha,
        'min_child_weight': min_child_weight,
        'gamma': gamma,
        'scale_pos_weight': scale_pos_weight,
        'n_estimators': int(n_estimators)
    }
       
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(**params)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred = model.predict(X_valid)
    rmse = mean_squared_error(y_valid, y_pred, squared=False)
    return -rmse

print('Performing hyperparameter tuning using Bayesian optimization...')
optimizer = BayesianOptimization(f=xgb_no_cv, pbounds=pbounds, random_state=100)
optimizer.maximize(init_points=5, n_iter=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tune the n_estimators using `xgb.cv` function the way you have written your objective function now. The `num_boost_round=100` arg you provided dictates the number of estimators or trees.

If you want to tune the number of trees using bayesian optimization and the `bayes_opt` package, you could do the following:

```
def xgb_cv(max_depth, learning_rate, subsample, colsample_bytree, lambd, alpha, min_child_weight, gamma, scale_pos_weight, n_estimators):
    params = {
        'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
        'max_depth': int(max_depth),
        'learning_rate': learning_rate,
        'subsample': subsample,
        'colsample_bytree': colsample_bytree,
        'lambda': lambd,
        'alpha': alpha,
        'min_child_weight': min_child_weight,
        'gamma': gamma,
        'scale_pos_weight': scale_pos_weight,
        #'n_estimators': int(n_estimators) Comment this line out; you don't need it.
    }

    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = y_train)
    cv_result = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=n_estimators, early_stopping_rounds=10, nfold=10, metrics='error') #  <---- you need to set the number of estimators here and accept it as an arg to the function.
    return -cv_result['test-error-mean'].iloc[-1]


pbounds = {
    'max_depth': (3, 9),
    'learning_rate': (0.01, 0.5),
    'subsample': (0.1, 1),
    'colsample_bytree': (0.1, 1),
    'lambd': (1, 1),
    'alpha': (0, 0),
    'min_child_weight': (2, 10),
    'gamma': (0.1, 0.5),
    'scale_pos_weight': (1, 1),
    'n_estimators': (50, 500) # <---- You need to indicate the number of trees here
}

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(f=xgb_cv, pbounds=pbounds, random_state=100)
optimizer.maximize(init_points=5, n_iter=10)
```

You will see that the output looks something like this

```
Finding the optimal hyperparameters for you
|   iter    |  target   | colsam... | learni... | max_depth | min_ch... | n_esti... | subsample |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | -0.2955   | 0.8489    | 0.8007    | 96.94     | 13.15     | 175.6     | 0.7215    |
| 2         | -0.2955   | 0.4944    | 0.7284    | 22.43     | 17.86     | 53.4      | 0.6903    |
| 3         | -0.2955   | 0.1196    | 0.9502    | 80.75     | 14.41     | 249.1     | 0.8175    |
| 4         | -0.2955   | 0.5281    | 0.2122    | 36.19     | 6.461     | 437.7     | 0.5957    |
| 5         | -0.2955   | 0.1809    | 0.823     | 68.28     | 14.71     | 90.24     | 0.8593    |
| 6         | -0.2955   | 0.4291    | 0.3458    | 3.482     | 9.048     | 999.6     | 0.8837    |
| 7         | -0.2955   | 0.5517    | 0.7092    | 59.52     | 16.77     | 326.1     | 0.5883    |
| 8         | -0.3824   | 0.154     | 0.8636    | 82.13     | 8.917     | 883.9     | 0.9588    |
| 9         | -0.2955   | 0.5048    | 0.5417    | 99.5      | 19.78     | 579.3     | 0.7871    |
| 10        | -0.2955   | 0.9412    | 0.7301    | 81.52     | 14.84     | 247.2     | 0.6331    |
=================================================================================================
```

These changes worked for me. I hope this helps you out!